# PDO prepare() fails on one server only

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

The following code:

```
class Database {
    (...)
    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }
    (...)
}
```

Is failing on my online server with the following error:

```
2018/04/02 15:16:14 [error] 3472#3472: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/includes/pdodatabaseconnect.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/index.php(52): Database->query('SELECT * FROM s...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/includes/pdodatabaseconnect.php on line 38" while reading response header from upstream, client: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

Whereas the exact same code, mirrored, works fine on my local server. I can't see any `PDO` differences introduced in `PHP` versions that would create this different outcome. There's a few suggestions online for amending similar classes to fix the issue but this seems like hitting a nail with a sledgehammer - The code works on a different server with mirrored files and on another server running a different project but the exact same database class file.

I'm unsure of what possible differences a server configuration could make to executing the code when the version differences involved are only minor and I can't spot any changes that would reflect the error I'm seeing.

## Servers:

### local (MAMP)

PHP: 7.2.1 /
MySQL: 5.6.38 /
nginx: 1.13.2

### online (Ubuntu 16.04)

PHP: 7.0.28 / 
MySQL: 5.7.21 / 
nginx: 1.10.3

Comment: Your `$this->dbh` is null. Wrong configs?

Comment: Same nginx configs on both. I don't understand why it's null on my online server but executes fine on my local.

Comment: It's not nginx, it's MySql configs. Different username/password/host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a silly thing to overlook, the error was quite obtuse in pointing out the issue which was an incorrect database password. I would have appreciated an authentication error.

The fact I duplicated all the files and configs meant that I was too confident the sites were identical. I had, however, set up a database with different user accounts on each.

Comment: Please delete your question as it can't help anyone in future

Comment: @Justinas This question and answer would have helped me immensely while I was researching the problem? The answer correlates to the question and I found nothing else suggesting this error was a mysql authentication issue. Where do we draw the line for who SO provides useful Q&A? I'm quite surprised at your suggestion.

Comment: It was your own mistake not properly setting configs. There is plenty of questions with sql configs check suggestion.

Comment: Surely a significant number of questions here arise from user mistakes or misunderstandings? I feel you are projecting your own perspective onto the value of this question and answer too much and narrowing the use of SO to an unrealistic minority. My question shows that I was not aware of any sql authentication issues and my answer stated that I felt the error didn't highlight this strongly. It's easy to suggest a library of answers is available in a subject once the answer has revealed that subject to be relevant. I didn't find any correlating the error with sql authentication.